# Fortran Intent (in)

Tags: arguments, fortran

I am having a problem with this simple code, giving me the following error. 
Somehow it is saying that there is a conflict with the `Intent (in)` attribute.

```
gfortran -o build/lib/larsa.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/larsa.f
lib/larsa.f:2701.8:

 sep, sty, shr               &
    1
Error: PROCEDURE attribute conflicts with INTENT attribute in 'sep' at (1)
lib/larsa.f:2710.17:

If (Len_trim (sep) > 0) Then
             1
Error: 'string' argument of 'len_trim' intrinsic at (1) must be CHARACTER
```

This is the subroutine

```
Subroutine write_separator_new  &
  (                             &
    sep, sty, shr               &
  )

Character (len=*), Intent(in) :: sep, sty
Integer, Intent(in), Optional :: shr

Character (len=65) :: a, fmt

If (Len_trim (sep) > 0) Then
  a = Repeat (sep(1), 60)
Else
  Write (*,*) ""
End If

End Subroutine write_separator_new
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexing of character strings requires `:`

```
a = Repeat (sep(1:1), 60)
```

The compiler assumed `sep` is a a function, because you used it as such and not as a character string.